# Google Sheets Match / Query from Multiple Dynamic Dropdowns

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Sheet that I need to query data from another tab to match 4 if/or dynamic drop downs and 1 if/and dynamic dropdown.  It's a stumper on my part.  I've attached the sheet as well as a 4 min explanation video.  Thanks in advance!

Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rUtTJkvFKFI8Q6lnRtxNpky5bYe9u8BZBok0M8hwZ7o/edit?usp=sharing

Video:

https://www.loom.com/share/392fd41c5c0844d6ad7df308d1af9f6c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({'Sub List'!A2:AE, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!L2:U),,999^99)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!V2:AE),,999^99))},
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, 
 IF(B1="",,"Col32 contains '"&B1&"'"), 
 IF(B2="",,"Col32 contains '"&B2&"'"), 
 IF(B3="",,"Col32 contains '"&B3&"'"), 
 IF(B4="",,"Col32 contains '"&B4&"'"), 
 IF(B6="",,"Col33 contains '"&B6&"'"))&""), 999^99, 31)
```

[image: 0]

---

for `OR` logic use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({'Sub List'!A2:AE, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!L2:U),,999^99)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!V2:AE),,999^99))},
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" or ", 1, 
 IF(B1="",,"Col32 contains '"&B1&"'"), 
 IF(B2="",,"Col32 contains '"&B2&"'"), 
 IF(B3="",,"Col32 contains '"&B3&"'"), 
 IF(B4="",,"Col32 contains '"&B4&"'"), 
 IF(B6="",,"Col33 contains '"&B6&"'"))&""), 999^99, 31)
```

---

for combo (`OR` between yellow cells and `AND` for green cell)

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({'Sub List'!A2:AE, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!L2:U),,999^99)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Sub List'!V2:AE),,999^99))},
 "where ("&TEXTJOIN(" or ", 1, 
 IF(B1="",,"Col32 contains '"&B1&"'"), 
 IF(B2="",,"Col32 contains '"&B2&"'"), 
 IF(B3="",,"Col32 contains '"&B3&"'"), 
 IF(B4="",,"Col32 contains '"&B4&"'"))&")"&
 IF(B6="",," and Col33 contains '"&B6&"'"), 0), 999^99, 31)
```